# Can you physically stop someone from commiting suicide?

Tags: death-note

Once you write suicide as the cause of death, the Death Note possesses victim and they commit suicide e.g. Naiomi Misora.

What would happen if you were to physically prevent that person from killing themselves?

For example, if Light were to physically restrain Naiomi before she hung herself, would the Death Note default to heart attack since the victim is incapable of fulfilling it?

Comment: Is there any case , any rule that say , if the victim do not die with the reason written in death note will die in due to heart attack

Comment: Either, she starves herself to death, or she dies of a heart attack. Basically if something is not possible/plausible of happening it will just default in a heart attack. [Unless having a heart attack is impossible](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14564/6166).

Answer (score 4):

Second paragraph from "How to Use: LV"

> In the occasion where the cause of death is possible but the situation is not, only the cause of death will take effect for that victim. If both the cause and the situation are impossible, that victim will die of heart attack.

So yes, the victim should have a heart attack if they are unable to kill themselves at the specified time.